# Using lambda expression in constructor of Timeline object cause error

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, lambda

Following statement is **proposed** to be changed to a lambda expressions in NetBeans.

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000), new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                //do something
            }
}));
```

But, when I apply the supposed change (Alt+Enter), I've got:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000), (Event event) -> {
 //do something
}));
```

When this won't compile with message:

> no suitable constructor found for KeyFrame(Duration, (Event
>   eve[...]}}}) - arguments mismatch

The questions is why NetBeans suggests something it can't implement ? And how to actually use the lambda function in Timeline constructor?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`KeyFrame` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html#KeyFrame-javafx.util.Duration-javafx.event.EventHandler-javafx.animation.KeyValue...-) you are calling takes an `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`, not an `EventHandler<Event>`.

So you need

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000), (ActionEvent event) -> {
 //do something
}));
```

The reason NetBeans is confused and inserts the incorrect code is because you start with a *raw type* for your event handler anonymous inner class:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000), new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                //do something
            }
}));
```

(I would expect NetBeans to issue a warning here, as well as the suggestion to use a lambda expression.)

Normal good coding practice would use a properly-typed event handler:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                //do something
            }
}));
```

in which case NetBeans would be able to replace it with the correct lambda expression.

Comment: I feel the need to point out that IDEs are terrible at auto-generating lambdas.  If it had been written as just `event -> { /* code */ }` (instead of ‘(ActionEvent event) -> { … }’, this wouldn’t have been an issue in the first place.